# CSS Grid with some elements spanning rows, others spanning columns

Tags: css, css-grid

For the items shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/nhsegal/pen/dymBgoG), I would like "mango" to stretch from the very top to the very bottom.

Since

```
.orange {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

worked for the orange element. I thought

```
.mango {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 3
}
```

would work, but it has no effect. Why doesn't `grid-row` work? I also tried experimenting with grid-flow setting for `.fruit-box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have 3 rows here. Try this:

```
.mango {
    background: yellow;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1/3; /* FROM 1 to 3 */
}
```

And if you use:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 2fr);
```

To establish your grid you can extend your cells to the last row (regardless of how many rows you may have) using -1, like this:

```
.mango {
    background: yellow;
    grid-row: 1/-1; /* from 1 to the end */
}
```